# Android 11 Wireless Debugging pairing and persistent connection

Tags: debugging, adb, remote-debugging, android-sdk-tools, android-11

My question actually consists of two:

1. `adb pair` command was added recently in 30 version of Android platform-tools, but official Linux repos (in particular, Ubuntu 18.04 and Debian 10) have only 27 version as latest. Is there any way to be up-to-date without manually downloading the latest archive from the website and placing it in the system?
2. I'm using wireless debugging for some device monitoring and home automation purposes, so I need to have the connection persistent (at least while the device is connected to my home network). Is there any way to keep the connection without root and doing `setprop persist.adb.tcp.port 5555`? Or at least do not disable "Wireless Debugging" options after the reboot and keep the port number.